# Java, формирование .docx

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

Стоит задача формирования отчета в виде документа MS Word (.docx).
Сам документ должен содержать заголовок и таблицу из нескольких столбцов.

Для реализации наткнулся на Apache POI.
В прицнипе, все просто:

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFTable table = doc.createTable(3, 3);    
table.getRow(1).getCell(1).setText("EXAMPLE OF TABLE");
table.getRow(2).getCell(2).setText("only text");

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("simpleTable.docx");
doc.write(out);
out.close();
```

Но! Уж очень он тяжеловесный, для такой простой задачи придется тащить

```
xmlbeans*.jar
poi*.jar
poi-ooxml*.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas*.jar
```

А это где-то **10Мб**!

**Вопрос** - есть ли более легковесное решение? 
На выходе нужен .docx файл, содержащий табличку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть еще один вариант, без сторонних библиотек.

Документ docx (Office Open XML) представляет собой набор XML-файлов в zip-архиве. Имея это в виду, вполне можно средствами XSLT-преобразований сгенерировать из шаблона готовый отчет.

PS. Если у вас нет жестких внешних ограничений, 10 МБ - не тот размер из-за которого стоит паниковать.

Answer (score 1):

Есть, минимум, два пути.
Работать с Word через COM. Но, тогда программа будет работать только под Windows.
Как вариант, можно ещё посмотреть в сторону [WordPrecessing](http://www.java400.de/default.html?Javactpe.htm). Но получится сделать то, что Вы хотите или нет, не уверен.

Answer (score 1):

Могу порекомендовать компонент компании Aspose: [Aspose.Words.](http://www.aspose.com/java/word-component.aspx) Конкретно под Java его не использовал, использовал под .NET, но от него остались исключительно позитивные впечатления. Продукт платный.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, посмотрю!

Answer (score 1):

Если файл с полностью фиксированной разметкой, решением для бедных будет набить шаблон прямо в ворде типа такого:

[image: Word]

Сохраняете его в .docx и добавляете в ресурсы своего приложения. Файл с картинки весит 10Kb. Затем в процессе выполнения программы распаковываете его как zip-архив (например, с помощью стандартного [`ZipFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html)), там есть файл `word/document.xml`, в котором по факту всё содержимое. Читаете его в память (в кодировке UTF-8) и делаете поиск с заменой, заменяя всякие `{{{Header1}}}` на произвольное содержимое (не забудьте, что надо эскейпить в XML `<`, `>` и `&`). Генерируете новый zip-файл с расширением .docx (можно использовать стандартный [`ZipOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html)). Туда записываете изменённый `word/document.xml`, остальные файлы копируете из ресурсного зипа без изменений.

Если требуются структурные изменения, можно генерировать `document.xml` с помощью DOM или XSLT. В принципе в таком варианте тоже ничего сложного.